# Not getting current location using cordovaGeolocation

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation

I tried to get current location of my app using cordovaGeolocation but failed to get.
My GPS is on but I can't get current location
following is my code

```
var posOptions = {timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
                   $cordovaGeolocation
                      .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
                      .then(function (position) {

                      lat  = position.coords.latitude
                      long = position.coords.longitude
                  console.log("lat " +  lat + " long " +long);

                  }, function(err) {
                      // error

                      console.log("error");
                  });
                  var watchOptions = {timeout : 20000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
                  var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);

                   watch.then(
                        null,

                  function(err) {
                  console.log(err)
                  },

                  function(position) {
                   lat  = position.coords.latitude
                   long = position.coords.longitude
                  console.log(lat + '' + long)
                }
                );

              watch.clearWatch();
```

How can I get current location? Above code is not helped me to solve my issue.
I didn't get current location in my device
Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://www.gajotres.net/using-cordova-geoloacation-api-with-google-maps-in-ionic-framework/

It's very usefull!